# What's wrong with this C++ nested for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, sfml

```
for (int pixel = 0; pixel < imgVector.size(); pixel++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getSize().x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getSize().y; y++)
        {
            pulledImage.setPixel(x, y, sf::Color::Color(imgVector.at(pixel)));
            pixel++;
        }
    }
}
```

So in this code I am trying to loop through a vector and place its contents into an image using SFML, but unless if I have pixel++; placed inside of the loop it gets stuck, I feel that having pixel++; in the loop is incorrect and could cause problems with my program. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Define stuck please. Do you mean it never finishes?

Comment: Did you mean to do `pixel++` in 2 different places?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What is `imgVector().size()`? What do you mean by "gets stuck"?

Comment: Perhaps adding that `pixel++` just accelerated the loop to the point where you can actually seat through it (at the cost of correctness)

Comment: Yes, when I remove the pixel++; from the loop the program does not complete.

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing `pixel` too many times and end up accessing `imageVector` using an out of bounds index.

```
for (int pixel = 0; pixel < imgVector.size(); pixel++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getSize().x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getSize().y; y++)
        {
            pulledImage.setPixel(x, y, sf::Color::Color(imgVector.at(pixel)));

            // This line does not make sense.
            // Why do you need to increment pixel here?
            pixel++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am going to guess that you need something like:

```
size_t pixel = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < image.getSize().x; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < image.getSize().y; y++, ++pixel)
   {
      assert(pixel < imgVector.size());
      pulledImage.setPixel(x, y, sf::Color::Color(imgVector.at(pixel)));
   }
}
```

Comment: I beleve the problem is the loop does not work **without** that extra `pixel++`

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that `sf::Image::setPixel()` isn't  really made to be used to update the whole image. You're constantly locking/unlocking the data, which will have bad performance compared to direct access.

If you'd like to create an `sf::Image` from raw image data, I'd suggest you use one of the `sf::Image::create()` overloads instead:

```
sf::Image image;
image.create(width, height, reinterpret_cast<sf::Uint8*>(&imgVector[0]));
```

This should create a new image with all the image data in place. `width` and `height` must have the proper dimensions.